# Support user time zones

Tags: php, mysql

I allow my users to add events to my webapp. Users can originate from all around the world.

My current idea is to determine the user's time zone automatically (using an IP to location API) and insert it into the users table (I will also allow them to change it).

On the events table I will insert the event start date/end date in UTC.

Then, whenever I need to display the event info, I would take the event start date/end date from the table and do the calculation against the user's timezone.

Is that considered as good practice or is there a better way to do that?

Anything I should be aware of when doing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is indeed a good way. Also keep in mind that if you use the `TIMESTAMP` type in MySQL, MySQL handles the timezone converting for you. When you insert new dates/times to the database, MySQL converts it from the connection's timezone to UTC (`TIMESTAMP` is always stored in UTC). When you retrieve a `TIMESTAMP` field from database, MySQL converts it back to the connection's timezone.

So if you use `TIMESTAMP` fields in MySQL, all you need to do is tell the user's timezone to MySQL at start of each your page. You do so by:

```
SET time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki'
```

You can also use numeric timezones:

```
SET time_zone = '+02:00'
```

Keep in mind that you might need to install the tzinfo to MySQL first, which is trivial though (only for the non-numeric version though). Here's information about how to do it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

In a nutshell, this is the important part:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

Here's an example of how it works:

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test(foo TIMESTAMP);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET time_zone = '+00:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('2011-02-03 16:00:00');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET time_zone = '+02:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT foo FROM test;
+---------------------+
| foo                 |
+---------------------+
| 2011-02-03 18:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you don't use `TIMESTAMP` field, eg. you use `DATETIME` (which also supports wider range of dates), then you just need to make sure you always insert dates in UTC; I do this by always setting connection's timezone to `+00:00`. Then you can have a view helper in PHP that converts the datetime to the user's timezone, which is quite trivial to do with PHP's [DateTime](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and [setTimezone function](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php). There's an example in the last link. To use this method, you must make sure PHP is also set to use UTC as its default timezone, which you can do with this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Whichever method you use, you should always be aware of these facts:

- The PHP and MySQL connection's timezones should always be set to the same value so they're consistent with each other
- Generally it's a bad idea to mix `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` types with each other
- If you use `TIMESTAMP` type, set the timezone to the user's timezone
- If you use `DATETIME`  type, set the timezone to UTC and handle timezone convertions in PHP

Comment: So if the column EVENT_STARTDATE is set to timestamp, and I use mysql_query to set the timezone to the user's timezone, When I select the EVENT_STARTDATE it will be converted automatically to the user timezone?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what'll happen. :)

Comment: Attached a test-case in the answer about `TIMESTAMP` behavior.

Comment: GREAT answer, seriously. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Few thing I would consider:

- Provide the users the means to set the time zone manually.
- Assuming your users may change their location, let them specify the time zone for the event they add (or the location if you can get the time zome from that).

This way hopefully they won't miss anything :) Good luck with your webapp!